# remove many to many association symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have two entity "Product" and "User" with ManyToMany association.
and I want to add columns to this association .
 to do that i must create another entity and linked between them with a one-to-many and many-to-one relation.
so the problem is how to delete the first association "ManyToMany"

from:

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="products")
     */
    private $users;
}
```

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ManagementBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_products")
     */
    protected $products;
}
```

to:

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OrderProduct", inversedBy="products",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="OrderProduct_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $OrderProduct;
}
```

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderProduct", mappedBy="user",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $orderProducts;
}
```

```
class OrderProduct
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="OrderProducts",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="OrderProduct",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $products;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the reason why you want that/ what fields you're going to add? BEcause the solution to your litteral question is easy, but there might be an easier fix :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:
- Let doctrine do the job for you
- Let Mysql do it
The choice depends on you need.

For doctrine, use

```
/**
 * @var int
 *å
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="products", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $users;
```

For MySQL, tell to MySQL to do a cascade remove on delete with like: (You should update database schema in this case)

```
/**
 * @var int
 *å
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $users;
```

If you want it to be bidirectional, just add the same in the other side entity